# Run each function 4seconds apart

Tags: javascript

I have 4 functions and I'm trying to run each of them 4 seconds apart.

With my below code there is only a 4 second gap between StepOne and StepTwo, thereafter there is no gap between the rest of the steps. What am I doing wrong?

```
/* Steps */
function StepOne() {
    console.log("Step One");
}
function StepTwo() {
    console.log("Step Two");
}
function StepThree() {
    console.log("Step Three");
}
function StepFour() {
    console.log("Step Four");
}

/* Sleep */
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

/* Run each function 4 seconds apart */
StepOne();
sleep(4000).then(() => { StepTwo(); });
sleep(4000).then(() => { StepThree(); });
sleep(4000).then(() => { StepFour(); });
```

Comment: `.then(()=>sleep(4000)).then(`...

Answer (score 2):

The `then` functions are not chained as they are supposed to be. Cleaner approach would be using `async/ await` like below

```js
function StepOne() {
  console.log("Step One");
}

function StepTwo() {
  console.log("Step Two");
}

function StepThree() {
  console.log("Step Three");
}

function StepFour() {
  console.log("Step Four");
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

/* Run each function 4 seconds apart */
async function runSteps() {
  StepOne();
  await sleep(4000);
  StepTwo();
  await sleep(4000);
  StepThree();
  await sleep(4000);
  StepFour();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runSteps()">Run steps</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing a gap between StepTwo, StepThree, and StepFour is that the sleep function is asynchronous, and all the sleep promises are being executed one after another without waiting for each other to finish.

You need to ensure that each sleep promise starts after the previous one has completed. You can do this by chaining the promises using `then():`

```js
StepOne();
sleep(4000)
    .then(() => { return StepTwo(); })
    .then(() => { return sleep(4000); })
    .then(() => { return StepThree(); })
    .then(() => { return sleep(4000); })
    .then(() => { return StepFour(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to queue tasks with a defined gap:

```js
function StepOne() {
  console.log("Step One");
}

function StepTwo() {
  console.log("Step Two");
}

function StepThree() {
  console.log("Step Three");
}

function StepFour() {
  console.log("Step Four");
}

async function gapQueue(ms, ...tasks) {
  for(let i=0;i<tasks.length;i++){
    i && await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    tasks[i]();
  }
}

const runSteps = () => gapQueue(1000, StepOne, StepTwo, StepThree, StepFour);
```

```html
<button onclick="runSteps()">Run steps</button>
```